# How to transform one polynomial curve into another

Tags: polynomials, mathematical-modeling, curves

I have a problem:
I have two polynomial splines:

[image: two splines]

For red curve I have used Rational fraction function with p=3/q=2 and for blue curve I have also used rational fraction function with p=1/q=3

It seems like both curves are of an equal nature. So, is there a way to transform one into another? Any answers or suggestions what to learn are happily welcome!

Comment: The curves are related means that there exist a function $f$ such that $c_1=f\circ c_2$ so in order to find $f$ you can just try to compute $c_1\circ c_2^{-1}$ ( in some interval in which it's defined)

Comment: Sorry, I am a biologist, could please give me more information about this "∘" sign?

Comment: This is the composition of functions, $f\circ c_2(t)=f(c_2(t))$, now  you have to find an expression of $f=c_1\circ c_2^{-1}$. How? for example we have $f(250)=c_1(c_2^{-1}(250))$ and $c_2^{-1}(250)=0$ because $c_2(0)=250$, so we have $f(250)=c_1(0)=250$. and $f(500)=c_1(2)$ because $c_2(2)=500$ which gives you $f(500)=800$ and using a lot of points you can find the function $f$. for example if $f(x)=ax+b$ then you can say that the variation of $c_1$ is linearly dependent of $c_2$ and you can write $c_1=ac_2+b$ which is the relation which relate the two concentrations